# Combining Eclipse RCP 3 and 4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Currently we have a large Eclipse RCP 3 application and we would like to port over to RCP 4. This will allow us to use the latest version of Eclipse and Java 8 onwards.

We can run the application in compatibility mode. This runs okay although perspective switcher toolbars aren't compatible so we need to use the equivalent in RCP 4.

Seeming as we only need one component to be changed it makes sense to first get it working with RCP 3 and RCP 4 combined and then to slowly port all the RCP 3 components across to 4.

[Here (At 5.5)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html#using-the-compatibility-mode) it mentions adding a `LegacyIDE.e4xmi` file and pointing at it in the `plugin.xml` by adding an extension parameter.

I've added the file (and also added a menu with menu items to test) and pointed the `plugin.xml` at it but the application loads with no changes. I've also looked at their linked example and I can't see any differences between theirs and mine. Their linked example also has no product file for me to test executing it. The file is also added to the build.properties.

Is there a way to check to see if the `e4xmi` file has successfully been applied?

How can I run the `SimpleRCPApp` they have linked on their page?

Comment: Be sure to specify -clean when running the RCP to make sure changes are picked up.

Comment: Yeah I've specified this. It just doesn't seem to be picking up the `e4xmi`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had specified the `LegacyIDE.e4xmi` correctly. The reason it wasn't working is that the project configuration needs to be cleared first.

To fix this I selected `Clear` in `Run Configurations` and ran the application.

This might be useful if anybody else gets similar issues.